# Paging display length on datatable is not shown

Tags: datatables

In the following table, the paging display length ("Show ... entries") is visible.
[image]

Now this is taken from my app:
[image]

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var table = $('#tbl_transaction').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data_transaction.php",
        "bPaginate":true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "columns": [
            { mData: 'username' } ,
            { mData: 'fullname' },
            { mData: 'the_date' },
            { mData: 'amount'}

        ],
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "buttons": [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    }); 
});
```

Strangely, it's hidden. [Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthChange) says

> Note that by default the control is shown at the top left of the
>   table. That can be controlled using dom and CSS.

I'm not well versed in CSS. So how should I do it?

Comment: I guess you are using some kind of framework that changes the datatables defaults `$.fn.dataTable.defaults` ...

Answer (score 1):

I see that you use button extension in your table.

I guess you use dom `Bfrtip` so the length changing input control will not be shown. You need to add `l` to your `sDom` or `dom`.

Example:

```
sDom: 'lBfrtip'
```

or

```
dom: 'lBfrtip'
```

Reference:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lp33hjcp/

Comment: Ah yes I used the button extension. Anyway, the code was wrong, so I updated. I already tried both of your suggestions, and still don't work. Hmmm

Comment: It's weird it should working fine.. Anyway which version of datatables you use? Try changing your bPaginate to paging, bProcessing to processing, mData to data and add l to your dom

Comment: I'm using v1.10.16. On latest Chrome (63.0.3239.132), the paging size only appears after the page is reloaded manually, but this will render the buttons invisible. But on latest Firefox (57.0.4), the paging size is visible. No issue at all so far. Hmm weird. Let me check again...

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I used to add the buttons to the datatable for the export etc:
http://datatables.net/reference/button/#tabletools.

Note the dom: 'Bfrtip', property does not have the letter 'L' in it.
Referring to this you will note that adding 'L' to the dom property adds the length selector:
http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom.
So the final dom should look like this:

```
dom: 'Blfrtip',
```

(note the additional 'L' after the 'B' character)

This will give you the export buttons and you can also select the row count to show.